# Disabling Keyboard Shortcuts didn't work in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

I'm a working with eclipse in Ubuntu. In eclipse, i frequently use a shortcut "Ctrl + Alt + Down Arrow" to duplicate the current line. I found that Ubuntu also has the same shortcut to switch the workspaces. So, my problem is when I press "Ctrl + Alt + Down Arrow", it calls the system's action. I tried this by disabling the keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu too. Still, it didn't work for me. Can anyone help me on this problem ?

Comment: Correction: Ctrl + Alt + Right/Left Arrow is used to switch workspaces in ubuntu. not Ctrl + Alt + Down Arrow.

Comment: whatever it is, the shortcut is related with the workspaces. it's not the main problem i guess. So, can you please help me out on this ?

Comment: @AlphaMale CTRL+ALT + (any arrow key) switches workspace in Ubuntu since at least 11.10. But I guess that also depends on whether you have your workspaces aligned "horizontally" or like a square. The latter is the default I think.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**1st solution: Remapping binding in eclipse**

Have you tried remapping the binding in the preferences?

Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys

Type "copy lines" in the filter.

Select the entry and edit the binding - I changed it to Ctrl+Alt+Numpad_4 and this seemed to work.

**2nd solution: Disable keystroke in compiz**

Note my actual fix for this is to disable a setting in compiz, but yo said this failed, here's what I did anyway in case it is useful:

System->Preferences-> ConpizConfigSettingsManager

Click "Advanced Search"

Type "down" in the filter box.

Click on "Desktop wall"

Disable "Move Down".

Comment: yaa, the first one is a good solution. But i don't want to change the shortcut for the copy row, cause i'm quite used to with it. But now this problem has been solved. It didn't work when i disabled the shortcut of Ubuntu. But rather than changing the shortcut of eclipse, i changed that of Ubuntu to some other key combination. Now it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In my case I am running ubuntu 17.10 + Gnome, inside the keyboard shortcut configuration UI I was only seeing one binding

```
Move to workspace above : Super + Page Up
Move to workspace below : Super + Page Down
```

But in fact there was 2 shortcuts defined on those actions, as you can see with the following command

```
> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up
['<Super>Page_Up', '<Control><Alt>Up']
```

So I simply re-bound the shortcut inside the UI to `Super + Page Up`, it erased the second binding

```
> gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-up
['<Super>Page_Up']
```

Answer (score 2):

I am used to Ctrl + Alt + Down shortcut and CompizConfigSettingsManager method didn't work for me.

But I found solution in my Ubuntu Studio 14.04 (XFCE):

- Open Windows Manager: `xfwm4-settings`
- Go to Keyboard tab
- Scroll down to `Lower worskpace` Action
- Hit Clear button

Copy line shortcut works fine in Eclipse now.

Comment: This works great in Xubuntu 22.04.4.

Answer (score 1):

```
System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Switch to workspace above

System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Navigation > Switch to workspace below

System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Launchers > Key To Show The HUD
```

Disable or reassign these

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu uses Openbox. System bindings can be found in `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`. Search it for `<keybind key="C-A-Down">` and `<keybind key="C-A-Up">`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Ubuntu 18.04 changing the setting in UI was not reflected in gsettings get... I achieved desired change with the same gsetting tool.
First, check current setting:

```
 $ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down
['<Super>Page_Down', '<Control><Alt>Down']
```

Then set new setting (note that setting needs to be quoted):

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down  "['<Super>Page_Down']"
```

Then check new setting:

```
$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings switch-to-workspace-down
['<Super>Page_Down']
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 do the following:

1. Enter the Settings -> Devices -> Keyboard.
2. In 'Navigation' menu click on the 'Move to workspace below' definition.
3. Click on 'Backspace' to delete ALL current shortcuts, and then click on 'Set' above.
4. Click again on the 'Move to workspace below' and press your desired shortcut (i.e. Super + Page Down) and then 'Set' above.

Now 'Ctrl Alt Down' is available, enjoy!